# Django filter exclude with ReverseManager

Tags: django, filter, django-queryset

I have a model `Tenant` and a model `SocialMediaContextTenant` that has a foreign key to the `Tenant` model.

```
class SocialMediaContextTenant(AbstractSocialMediaContext):
    tenant = models.ForeignKey('campaigns.Tenant')
    secret = models.CharField(...)
```

I would like filter all tenants where a connected `SocialMediaContextTenant` has the `secret` field set.

So far I have this query

```
Tenant.objects
      .exclude(socialmediacontexttenant__secret='')
      .values_list('id', flat=True)
```

But the exclude filter does not seem to work, since I still get results with an empty `secret` field

Comment: Probably secret has null value. Try to combine two exclude methods: `.exclude(socialmediacontexttenant__secret='').exclude(socialmediacontexttenant__secret__insull=True)`

Comment: Then I get an error `django.core.exceptions.FieldError: Unsupported lookup 'insull' for CharField or join on the field not permitted.`

Comment: My bad, it should be `__isnull`.

Comment: Awesome that worked! Can you formulate it as a question then I'll accept it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like `secret` field has null value, not empty string. To exclude these records use [`__isnull`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/models/querysets/#std:fieldlookup-isnull) lookup:

```
Tenant.objects.exclude(socialmediacontexttenant__secret='').exclude(socialmediacontexttenant__secret__isnull=True)
```